# Global Name Error while using Tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy

I am quite new to python and am trying to learn how create basic twitter bots. I am trying to use the streaming API and fetch handle names. I check from a file if a post has already been made to the fetched handle. If yes, then I ignore else I post. The code works when a fresh handle comes in but when a duplicate handle comes, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop>Stream-Reply_new.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Stream-Reply_new.py", line 50, in <module>
    twitter_stream.filter(track=['#musiclovers'])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 430, in filter
    self._start(async)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 346, in _start
    self._run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 286, in _run
    raise exception
NameError: global name 'status' is not defined

import tweepy
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
import json
import time

consumer_key = 
consumer_secret = 
access_token = 
access_secret = 

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

def check():
    datafile = file('C:\Users\User\Desktop\Growth Handles.txt', 'r')
    found = False
    for line in datafile:
        if status.user.screen_name in line:
            found = True
            break
    return found


class MyListener(StreamListener):


    def on_status(self, status):
        f=status.user.screen_name
        if check() :
            pass
        else:
            Append=open('Growth Handles.txt' , 'a' )
            Append.write(f)
            Append.close()
            Reply='@' + f + ' Check out Tomorrowland 2014 Setlist . http://.... '
            api = tweepy.API(auth)
            api.update_status(status=Reply)
            time.sleep(45)
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)
        return True



twitter_stream = Stream(auth, MyListener())
twitter_stream.filter(track=['#musiclovers'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in tweepy , but the only place I can see 'status' being used as a global name , but is not defined , is in 'check()' function , where is tries to check `if status.user.screen_name in line:` , but status is not defined as a global name .

Maybe you should send the status as a parameter to this function -

```
def check(status):
    datafile = file('C:\Users\User\Desktop\Growth Handles.txt', 'r')
    found = False
    for line in datafile:
        if status.user.screen_name in line:
            found = True
            break
    return found

def on_status(self, status):
    f=status.user.screen_name
    if check(status) :
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write the code using try except.

```
try:
    f=status.user.screen_name
    Append=open('Growth Handles.txt' , 'a' )
    Append.write(f)
    Append.close()
    Reply='@' + f + ' Check out Tomorrowland 2014 Setlist . http://.... '
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    api.update_status(status=Reply)
    time.sleep(45)
return True
except Exception: 
  pass
```

That way you can handle your errors in the except but the main program will continue to run due to the 'pass'.